# How to Retain File Names that are being mangled when I Move/ Cut Files from Recycle Bin to a selected folder

Tags: windows-8.1, recycle-bin

How To? Retain File Names being mangled when Move/ Cut select Files from Recycle Bin to a selected location

Move/ Cut select Files from Recycle Bin to a selected location retaining File Names without name mangling?

"**Windows Behavior**" when I cut/ paste or drag-drop the files from Recycle Bin to some location/ folder, the file names are mangled when they reach the target location.

For example, $REA9O58.xxx (my original file name does not look anything like that).

The only option Recycle Bin gives is:

- **Right Click > Restore**
  (do not wish for files to go back and mixup with other files in Original Folder) or
- **Right Click > Cut + Paste / Left Click > Drag-Drop**
  (When pasted or Drag & Dropped to new location, the original name is mangled).

Any way around this to put select files into other location folders from Recycle Bin?

Note: Found this bit of Script but that only lists what the UI shows. I wonder if Windows will allow movement of files without name mangling.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716521/listing-files-in-recycle-bin

PS: OS: Win 8.1 x64

Comment: The behiavor you describe has more to do with NTFS then the recycle bin.  The problem I have, i have never experienced the behavior you described, in the 25 years I have been using Windows.  I am able to delete a file, and cut that file to a new location, and it retains it's original file 100% of the time.  Please provide a screenshot of how your viewing a file with a "mangled" filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked:

Select File(s) > **Right** Click > Drag & Drop > **Move Here**

I am not sure why but the bolded parts of the sequence above seem to have solved the other ways that are not working.

With this sequence, the file names were retained and no filename mangling occurred.